# How to call the second row in an Active record table

Tags: database, variables, activerecord

I have two variables that were being set to session tokens for testing purposes so my code was as follows:

```
@auth_token = Session.first.token
@auth2_token = Session.last.token
```

I now have the need for a third session token and I was wondering how I could go about this in the before statement. Can someone tell me how I could set the variable to the second record in the sessions table.

```
@auth_token = Session.first.token
@auth2_token = Session.limit(2).token   
@auth3_token = Session.last.token
```

I have tried limit(2).token but it doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@auth_token, @auth2_token, @auth3_token = Session.limit(3).map(&:token)
```

You've failed with `limit(2).token` because `limit` returns 2 objects and you need to apply `token` method to every of them.